# Compute the directional derivative

Tags: derivatives

Compute the directional derivative. Be sure that you use a unit vector.

$q(x,y,z)=4x^2-3y^3+2z^2$ at $(0, 1, 2),$ $t=2i-3j+k$

Answer given is $35/(14^{0.5})$

Comment: I've tried but only got 35.

Comment: When you take the directional derivative take care to make the vector you dot with a unit vector.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{2^{2}+(-3)^{2}+1^{2}}=\sqrt{14}$